# How can I redirect my Laravel page to a page I specified?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my `web.php` and `logincontroller.php`.  I want to redirect the user whose user type is 'admin' on every successful login to the 'dashboard' page, but in every successful attempt it redirects to the 'home' page. How can I solve it?

**web.php**

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('admin.dashboard');
    });
});
```

**Login Controller PHP**

```
//login controller PHP
protected function redirecTo()
{
    //login
    if (Auth::user()->usertye == 'admin') {
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    } else {
        return '/home';
    }
}
```

I can access it when I type `/dashboard` instead of URL from the `home` page, but I want to redirect those whose user type is **admin** to the `dashboard` page instead of this `home` page.

Comment: Have you tried this: `return '/dashboard;'` instead of `return 'redirect()->route('dashboard');`
Also check if `Auth::user()->usertye` condition ever works.

Comment: usertye == 'admin'. seems like a typo

Comment: There was an error writing the function. redirecTo -> redirectTo. Thank you all